# Flipper not show react-native log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use flipper to debug my app, but don't know how flipper not show my log on console, BUT it show native app log ( in this case is android log)

React-native log:

[image]

Native app log:

[image]

App log:
[image]

The setting is default, i thought flipper work out of the box

React-native version `0.63.3`

Comment: I have the same problem, all other plugins work but I cant see the logs. Did you solve it @CODEforDREAM

Comment: Flipper works out of the box but react-native ships with outdated flipper, can you try upgrading flipper? Here is a guide for it: https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Any new update on showing the logs. ? @BrijeshBhakta